# AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior onkeypress

Tags: java, ajax, web, wicket

I have a list of items, above which there is an input fields.
The input field is a filter, it should filter the list based on the text you key in to the input field.

For example :
If you type "th", it should filter the list so that all the items should start with "th".

For this I am using AjaxFormComponentUpadingBehavior("onkeypress").
But this does not seem to be working they way it should.
When I key in something it clears up that and takes the cursor to the first letter of the input field.

I have tried onkeyup and onkeydown, and all of them act the same way.
For now I am doing the filter on a link click which works, but I want it to be as seamless as onkeypress.

Is there a way to achieve this?
I am using wicket 1.4.x

Here is the code :

```
        // Customer Filter input field
        customerFilterTxt = new TextField<String>("customerFilterTxt", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "slectedCustomerFilterStr"));
        customerFilterTxt.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        customerListViewContainer.add(customerFilterTxt);

        // Ajax behavior for customer group filter auto complete input filed
        AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior customerGroupFilterBehave = new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onkeypress") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                List<CustomerGroupBean> filterList = new ArrayList<CustomerGroupBean>();
                if(Util.hasValue(selectedCustomerGroupFilterStr)) {
                    String str = selectedCustomerGroupFilterStr.toUpperCase();

                    for(CustomerGroupBean group : custGroupList) {
                        if(group.getRightGroupName().toUpperCase().contains(str)) {
                            filterList.add(group);
                        }
                    }

                    custGroupListView.setList(filterList);

                } else {
                    custGroupListView.setList(custGroupList);
                }

                target.addComponent(customerFilterTxt);
                target.addComponent(custGroupListViewContainer);
            }
        };
        customerGroupFilterTxt.add(customerGroupFilterBehave);
```

Comment: Please post some Code. Does it behave like that in another browser?

Comment: I have just edited the question with the code for the input field and the ajax behavior.

As far as browsers go, I have tried it in chrome(latest), firefox(latest), and IE 11 and all gave me same results.

If you happen to have wicket 1.4.x, just try creating an ajax behavior with onkeypress, I am pretty sure it ll work the way I just explained in the question.

Comment: Try `OnChangeAjaxBehavior` instead of `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior `

Comment: Both behave the same way, but I fixed the problem.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the input field to the update call within the update method. This instructs Wicket to replace the input field, rendering the text field again. Thats why the cursor jumps to the first position. Why do you add the text field to the update? I don't see any imperative for it. Also you may want to use the event `"onkeyup"`.

Comment: Adding the input field was a mistake.

So what I did right now is, I blocked that statement, changed the onkeypress to onkeyup and it kind of solved some problems but not fully.

It still jumps the cursor to the first as soon as I finish keying in.

Comment: I build a very simple page and can't reproduce the effect: http://pastebin.com/LHfzCJvY

Comment: Actually, I found what the problem was,

As we can't add a repeater to an AjaxRequestTarget, I had to put that in a container so that I can add the container to the AjaxRequestTarget in order to refresh the list.


The problem was, the filter input field was also in the same container, so whenever I was refreshing the container, the input field was also getting refreshed and hence the cursor was jumping.

I had to remove the filter input field from the container and that did it.

Thanks a lot :)